# Does a laptop with i7-7500U CPU necessarily have Intel Graphics hardware?

Tags: linux, laptop, drivers, graphics-card, cpu

I have been curious about Intel HD graphics for a while now. My question is does a laptop with Core i7 ([i7-7500U](https://ark.intel.com/products/95451/Intel-Core-i7-7500U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_50-GHz-)), necessarily have Intel® HD Graphics 620. Or it can either have it or not? I mean is Intel graphics integral to processors supporting them or are they optional? I checked out a laptop with this cpu model which had NVidia GeForce 920M. Can we say that this laptop (Ideapad 310 - Q) has two graphics cards (both Intel and NVidia)? If so, how these two graphics work together? 
This is an important question for me, because I am an open-source fan and I would like to make sure I get a machine with Intel graphics because Intel graphics drivers are highly open-source and I love that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,
 you can have two graphics cards.
1 is integrated graphics on the same die as your CPU
2 is the additional graphics card on a different chip manufactured either by NVidia or AMD

Depending on your operating system your computer may decide to use one or the other in different applications. The intel graphics is usually used when there is not much performance required and power efficiency is very important.
Your OS would usually switch to using the dedicated graphics card when you launch a 3D application like a game.

In your specific case you have the  intel HD 620 which is bundled together with every i7 7500u CPU.

The IdeaPad 310 has 2 graphics card and that is the integrated graphics that comes with its intel CPU - intel HD 620 and the NVidia 920MX

Comment: Thanks. Can the user set any preference to using one of the chips?

Comment: Yes depending on what specific graphics card you have and what operating system you use.
If you have intel HD graphics and an NVidia graphics card and you are using Windows you can change this through the NVidia control panel.

Comment: Within NVidia control panel you will have to click on Manage 3D Settings.
There you will see two tabs. Global settings and Program settings.
Global setting you can choose the graphics card that you want to use all the time (better leave this at auto)
Program setting you can choose the graphics card that you want to use with each specific program.

Answer (score 1):

Sone notebooks don't show the Intel HD graphic like the [ASUS ROG Strix GL502VM](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Asus-ROG-Strix-GL502VM-Notebook-Review.187341.0.html)

> **Notebooks with an integrated and a dedicated GPU usually offer an automatic switching option. The dedicated GPU takes over when the
>   laptop deals with intensive graphics processing. Otherwise, the
>   integrated GPU is used, so as to save on power. The Asus GL502VM does
>   not conform to this principle: the HD Graphics 530 is turned off. The
>   Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060 is always running.**

So you have to check the manual and tests if your notebook has the switching mode ([optimus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Optimus)) or if it only uses the dedicated nVIDIA card.